# Recommended Socket Server frameworks

Tags: language-agnostic, frameworks, sockets

I've written my fair share of loops around accept() or select(); fork() or Thread.start().

I'd like to avoid doing it again. I'd prefer not to re-use my own code. And I'd like to take advantage of benefits that a 'serious' framework offers, such as preforking, thread pooling, etc.

What frameworks do you recommend - in any language - that accept socket connections and present the programmer with a stream handle to work with? There are plenty of well known ones for HTTP. I'm looking for something one protocol level lower down.

Two I'm aware of are:

- [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty/index.html) for Java
- [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html) for Python

Answer (score 0):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) for Python is another option.

It's very powerful but has quite a steep learning curve (although maybe not for someone with previous experience of this style of programming).

Answer (score 0):

With Erlang it is very easy to craft HTTP / TCP servers whilst still fully supporting threading (well, in the case of Erlang, there are all processes).